# Marvel comics: pink alien villain (character ID)

Tags: marvel, comics, aliens, character-identification

A pink-colored villain, female, I believe, of an alien species with a small body but a very large head, and the ability to shoot some sort of electric blast out of the center of her forehead, as well as possibly using that blast for mind-control purposes. She is pretty scary looking, with pointed teeth and a perpetually angry expression.

The scene, as I remember it, features various characters interacting and fighting in some underground area (a sewer or railroad tunnel or similar) while above the platform, in some sort of control room or capsule or something, this pink character observes and attempts to influence the outcome. At some point she enters combat as well, though she is physically weak so needs to rely on her forehead-lightning.

The characters 'down below' include: definitely Falcon and Captain America; I believe Kingpin -- who may have been associated with the pink alien in some way; and surely others that I am forgetting. Leaning towards Hulk, but not positive.
I think besides actual combat there was a situational emergency, like maybe the room collapsing or something.

I have searched for this character and this scene several times on Marvel character boards but have found nothing thus far. Any ideas?

EDIT: FYI, this is from a comic I read circa 1990 or so, though it was a Marvel compilation, so it was probably older than that.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the character would be [Thursday Rubinstein aka Ruby Thursday](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thursday_Rubinstein_(Earth-616)). Not sure what issue you read though.

Comment: https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Clarice_Ferguson_(Earth-616)?

Comment: One of these; https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Pink_Skin

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It is definitely not Thursday Rubinstein or Clarice Ferguson, both of whom seem to have normal humanoid proportions; this character is physically small with a giant head; all features are monster-like including the face (which has identifiable eyes, mouth etc. unlike Thursday Rubinstein)

Comment: I have just perused the entire "Pink Skin" page and, sadly (or not?) I am 99% certain that the character I'm thinking of is not on there (yet). I have a very clear memory of its face, posture, and ability to project forehead blasts, and none of the characters listed seem to match that....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Might you be thinking of ***[Denise Baranger](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Denise_Baranger_(Earth-616))***, also known as Animus...?

She had two forms -- one human, one monstrous -- but her monstrous form certainly fits your description, and she did project beams from her forehead in that form.

She also featured in a multi-part storyline which spanned *Captain America Vol. 1 #228-230* and *Incredible Hulk Vol. 1 #232*, and featured Captain America, the Falcon, and the Hulk.

The Kingpin didn't feature in this story, but there was a character called resembling him, called [Eugene "Kligger" Stivak](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Eugene_Stivak_(Earth-616)). You can see him in a couple of panels of the first page I posted below.

[image]

<sub>*[Captain America Vol. 1 #230](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Captain_America_Vol_1_230)* (February, 1979)</sub>

[image]

<sub>*[Incredible Hulk Vol. 1 #232](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Incredible_Hulk_Vol_1_232)* (February, 1979)</sub>

Comment: Guess I was wrong about her being physically weak though! And about that being Kingpin -- though physically very similar.

Comment: Hulk was focused on Captain America on the previous page, and then was suddenly attacked by Animus and Moonstone at the same time , from different angles. He was down for a few pages, but then got back up and beat Animus by smashing her club, which she said was the source of her power. Hard to tell quite how strong Animus was. She did seem to be able to stand up to the Hulk briefly, but Captain America was beating her one-on-one in an earlier appearance.

Comment: Next to the Hulk, everyone is physically weak.